# request.original_url and undefined local variable or method `request' for main

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dashing

I'm starting my adventure with ruby, and got stuck in one procedure I want to do so to the point, I'm using dashing to create some dashboards.

But I need a instruction to read my URL to get query parameters from it,

I was trying to use:

```
url = request.original_url
print(url)
```

But all Im getting is

> '<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method 'request' for main:Object (NameError)

Am I missing something, maybe some gem or require?

Comment: Update your complete action in code. Is this code in controller or model. When you get this error?

Comment: Which version of rails you are using?

Comment: 3.2 rails and controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the `request` method of controller, but you can't because you are in `Model` class at this point.

**Note:** Update your code so it will be more clear. for your reference regarding [**`request.original_url`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url). You may want to read up on [**MVC in Rails**](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/) or [**MVC in general**](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/).